# class file for org.bouncycastle.cert.ocsp.BasicOCSPResp not found

Tags: java, netbeans, itext, bouncycastle

I made the mistake of running clean on my Netbeans project, which has had no major API changes at all lately. Now the build suddenly fails with the following error:
class file for org.bouncycastle.cert.ocsp.BasicOCSPResp not found

To my knowledge, I'm not using any such library in my project. I did find that it is an iText dependency of some sort, but even when I comment out all of my iText-related code, the error persists.

I have tried adding the 1.49 version of bouncycastle to my Netbeans project, to no avail. (Actually, that did cure the first bouncycastle no-class-found error I had, but this second error was the next problem). I looked in the archive and found that BasicOCSPResp is found under org.bouncycastle.ocsp. I also tried peeking at versions 1.47, 1.46, and even 1.32 and found BasicOCSPResp under org.bouncycastle.ocsp and not org.bouncycastle.cert.ocsp in all of them.

Here is the build stacktrace:
Note: Creating static metadata factory ...

```
error: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for      
org.bouncycastle.cert.ocsp.BasicOCSPResp not found
```

An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception.
Consult the following stack trace for details.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for org.bouncycastle.cert.ocsp.BasicOCSPResp not found
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor.process(CanonicalModelProcessor.java:407)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:627)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:556)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:701)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bouncy Castle has classes in several jars.  For `BasicOCSPResp` you need to make sure a bcpkix jar is on the classpath.  The latest version is [bcpkix-jdk15on-149.jar](http://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcpkix-jdk15on-149.jar).

Comment: I put the jar (verified to contain org.bouncycastle.cert.ocsp.BasicOCSPResp) in netbeans-8.1/java/modules, netbeans-8.1/java/modules/ext, netbeans-8.1/enterprise/modules, netbeans-8.1/enterprise/modules/ext.  Still complains.  Which is the classpath?