# `java.lang.VerifyError: class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive` after installing Neo4j-Devise gem on JRuby

Tags: devise, openssl, neo4j, jruby, bouncycastle

I'm pretty new to programming and have been trying to follow the Team Treehouse tutorials.  However, whilst working on my own project, I've been building an app with JRuby and Neo4j.  I've managed to make my way through a few differences so far, but seem to be stuck now.  I've just installed the Neo4j-Devise gem and everything has been working ok, but now I seem to be getting this error whenever I try to start the server... or do anything useful really:

```
LoadError: load error: jopenssl/load -- java.lang.VerifyError: class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1083
 (root) at C:/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/jruby-openssl-0.9.4/lib/jruby-openssl.rb:5
require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1083
 (root) at C:/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:1
 each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
require at C:/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72
 each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613
require at C:/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70
require at C:/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59
require at C:/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132
require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1083
 (root) at C:/Sites/Knock4/config/application.rb:14
  tap at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1891
 (root) at C:/jruby-1.7.9/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/railties-3.2.16/lib/rails/commands.rb:1
require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1083
 (root) at script/rails:6
```

I have read a few other pages on here suggesting that similar errors can be caused by differences in Bouncycastle versions, but I've tried changing them (at least I think I have, perhaps I've been doing that wrong!) and I keep getting the same error.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

The gem file is as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.16'
gem 'jruby-openssl'
gem 'devise', '2.2.7'
gem 'devise-neo4j', :git => 'git://github.com/cfitz/devise-neo4j.git', :branch => 'devise2'
group :assets do
 gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
 gem 'therubyrhino'
 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'

group :development, :test do
 gem "rspec-rails"
end

gem "neo4j", ">= 2.2.0"
gem 'neo4j-admin'
```

Comment: not sure, maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843691/openssl-problems-in-jruby has the answer.

Comment: what does your gemfile look like?

Comment: I've added the gemfile to the question, hopefully that will help.  Not sure if you realise @Stefan, but that link links straight back to this question.

Comment: Please amend your question with the commands are you running. If there are multiple versions of bouncycastle being loaded, then perhaps instead of running `rails s` (for example), you can try `bundle exec rails s`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the `neo4j-admin-0.2.0-java` gem includes `lib/neo4j-admin/jars/bcprov-jdk16-140.jar`. Unpacking that JAR shows that there are bouncycastle classes included.

Looking at the [docs for ASN1Primitive](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Primitive.html), we can see that it inherits from `ASN1Object`. Running `javap` on the ASN1Object included in the above JAR, we can see what `equals` is defined as (extra lines removed):

```
$ javap ASN1Object.class | grep equals
  public final boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
```

This data correlates with this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212410/itext-bouncycastle-throws-java-lang-verifyerror-class-overrides-final-method). Looking at the `MANIFEST.MF` file at the root of the JAR, it says

```
Implementation-Version: 1.40.0
```

So JRuby is likely including a newer version of bouncycastle and you have a gem providing an older version; welcome to DLL Hell :-). I'm not sure of the best solution here. You could delete the `bcprov` JAR as a quick hack, but who knows what that might do. You should check to see if there is a newer version of the neo4j gems that might work around this. If not, you should probably file a bug with them so that they are aware (if there isn't one already).

**EDIT**

Here is [the bug report](https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j-admin/issues/12). It doesn't look to have been worked on in quite a while.

**EDIT 2**

Of course, if you don't need the `neo4j-admin` gem, you can probably remove it from your Gemfile and keep on trucking.

Comment: Thanks for the research into the problem, seems like you've nailed it!  I only installed neo4j-admin as I couldn't access the neo4j database through the command prompt, as you would with a SQL database in Rails using "rails console".  I don't suppose anyone knows another way of doing it?  On another note, trying to uninstall the neo4j-admin gem from the prompt also creates an error, I assume that just removing it from the gems list should do the trick?

Comment: I would expect that you could stop using the gem by removing that line from `Gemfile` and then run `bundle`. Then that gem shouldn't be loaded any more, unless something else needs it. You can check for that case in `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: I still seem to be getting the same error when either trying to uninstall the neo4j-admin gem, or removing it from the gemfile and running `bundle`.

Comment: Just for any future reference, it took a lot to uninstall this gem.  I've had to completely uninstall JDK, JRuby, Ruby and Rails before reinstalling it without neo4j-admin referenced in any documentation.  Although I think it was only JDK and JRuby that were needed.  It now _finally_ seems to be working ok.  Thanks for your help, I'll keep an eye on the bug report to see if any changes occur.