# Jmeter throwing error class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals

Tags: java, jmeter, bouncycastle

I am new to Jmeter.

I have created my own Java Request sampler and using eclipse, I created my jar file. Than I put the jar file under JMETER_HOME/lib/ext/

Then I launch Jmeter and I get below error

```
An error occurred: class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
errorlevel=1
```

I read the below article
[iText / BouncyCastle throws "java.lang.VerifyError: class overrides final method equals"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212410/itext-bouncycastle-throws-java-lang-verifyerror-class-overrides-final-method)

Does it mean that I am using older version of BC. How do I update to new version of BC?

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: There can be a possibility of your JAR conflicting with existing Jmeter libraries.

Comment: @Jmeter PerfTest  you are right. So I have kept my jar separate. I created a separate jar which calls my jar. Seems to be working but I do not like my approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 different versions of the BouncyCastle jars.

If your version is higher than the one embedded by the JDK, try upgrading it at JVM level if possible.

Otherwise, remove the one you have embedded.