# Gradle build docker image fails on duplicate libraries

Tags: hadoop, gradle, bouncycastle

I try to build a simple hadoop application using gradle. I would like to containerize this application. (https://github.com/geoHeil/lab04) using the gradle docker plugin (https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin).

Compilation works fine. However running `gradle dockerBuildImage` results in the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':dockerBuildImage'.
class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

Akkording to [iText / BouncyCastle throws "java.lang.VerifyError: class overrides final method equals"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212410/itext-bouncycastle-throws-java-lang-verifyerror-class-overrides-final-method) this means that there are several conflicting versions of this dependency.

I am not sure how to find / remove the library. A `gradle -q dependencies --configuration compile`does not seem to list this dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly simple answer:

You only need to move `bcprov-jdk15-143.jar out of /Library/Java/Extensions`

from https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/3365#issuecomment-132452254